# Algorithm that calculates decimal places of number

Tags: arithmetic, rational-numbers

**My background**.
I am a school student. Recently, we learned about rational numbers and irrational numbers. For example, we were told that rational numbers can always be written as a repeating decimal, that $\pi$ is an irrational number, and that the decimal represantion of irrational numbers aren't periodic (that is, the decimal places 'go on forever'). I was very curious about these things and asked the teacher why these facts he told us are true. I was really interested if there is some sort of argument that somehow shows that the decimal places of $\pi$ go on forever, for example. The answers of the teacher were very dissappointing: he just said that this isn't part of the curriculum. Obviously, this means that I have to find out these things on my own initiative.

**My question.** In this present question I am for now just interested in why the standard algorithm one uses to calculate the decimal places of a number is correct. We learned that one can calculate the decimal expression of a rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ by calculating:
$$a :b \quad=\quad p_1\text{ Remainder }r_1\\
r_1\cdot10 :b \quad=\quad p_2\text{ Remainder }r_2\\
r_1\cdot 10 :b \quad=\quad p_3\text{ Remainder }r_3\\
\vdots$$
Now I am wondering why $p_1.p_2p_3\dots$ is a decimal expression of the number $\frac{a}{b}$. In other words: why is $p_1 + p_2/10 + p_3/100 + \dots = \frac{a}{b}$? How can one prove this?

Comment: What you show here is just the usual _long division_ procedure extended to the right of the decimal point. Is your question why long division works?

Comment: ... and do you understand why long division works for giving an _integer_ quotient with remainder?

Comment: Yes, my question is why long division works.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: As for your second question: I don't really understand, isn't that my question?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Do you have an idea how to tag my question?

Comment: x @user354427: I wasn't sure whether that is your question. It looks like you're alright with the step that produces $p_1$ and $r_1$, so you can calculate (with pencil and paper) for example $788623\div 31 = 25439$ with remainder $14$, and know why what you're doing works?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes, the first step (that determines $p_1$ and $r_1$) is clear to me.

Comment: Do you then recognize that the extension to getting $p_2$ and $r_2$ takes you through exactly the same steps as if the original division had been $7886230\div 31$ instead?